# Django 1.7 migrations not being picked up

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

Using Django 1.7 and it's new migration I am running into a strange issue.

I split my settings files up into 3 files which I have always done pre version 1.7 eg...

```
/settings
  __init__.py
  base.py
  development.py
  production.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .base import *

if sys.argv[1] == 'runserver':
    from .development import *
else:
    from .production import *
```

Both `development.py` and `production.py` have there own database settings for there environment. However with the new migrations system running migrations does not detect anything UNLESS I put the database settings in the `base.py` files.

Should I modifity this line to the following:

```
 if sys.argv[1] == 'runserver' or sys.argv[1] == 'migrate':
```

**Or there a better way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid adding logic to your settings file, consider using che *--settings* option when testing with runserver, like this:

```
./manage.py --settings=project.settings.development runserver
```

You can also use environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to switch the settings module used by Django.

In your development enviroment you could set:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.development
```

While in production you could set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.production.

The details depend on the type of deployment and server you are using.

Personally in my development setup I use [virtualenv wrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and I set up the postactivate hook with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is run after this virtualenv is activated.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.local
cd /home/user/develop/git/project
```

In this way I can type

> workon project

And I have the environment variable correctly set, and my shell sent on the right folder.

You can have a base.py settings file with all your common settings, then in development.py (and production.py) you can do something like this:

```
from .base import *

DATABASES = ... customize DB settings used for development/production ...
```